# Can you define functions inline in D?

Tags: function, d, definition

I am wanting to do something like this:

```
void function() test = void function() { ... };
```

Is this possible? Also can I make function arrays like this:

```
void function()[] test = [
    void function() { ... },
    void function() { ... }
];
```

I know I could just use function pointers, but for my purpose the functions don't actually need a name, and will only be accessed from the array, so it seems quite redundant to give each one of them a declaration.

Comment: You most certainly want to check lambda functions (http://dlang.org/expression.html#Lambda). They have a very nice syntax in D. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, and you almost guessed the syntax. In the function literal, "function" goes before the return type:

```
void function() test = function void () {...};
```

Much of that is optional. This does the same (as long as the compiler can infer everything):

```
auto test = {...};
```

Further reading: http://dlang.org/expression.html#FunctionLiteral, http://dlang.org/function.html#closures

---

Also, you can just nest functions in D:

```
void main()
{
    void test() {...}
    test();
}
```